# Layout Android (Box Dialog)

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tentando construir um boxdialog para uma listview.
Estou tendo dificuldades em encontrar um exemplo para me basear e desenvolver minha solução.

Alguém conhece algum material para me indicar?
Segue uma foto do dialog esperado (acima do "i")

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você só precisa que seja exibido isso? no click?

Answer (score 1):

**Caio Sanchez Christino**, tive a mesma dúvida que você segue minha solução:

Utilize o metodo `setError()` para atribuir esse dialog, não sei como você quer (click ou automático), podem a implementação é a mesma.

**Exemplo de como implementar:**

```
   EditText agendado = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.agendado);
      if(resgate.isAgendado())
      {    
         agendado.setError("Agendado");
      }
```

**Isso vai gerar um pop-up:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode dar uma olhada na [Documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) para maiores informações

Comment: Eu usei o setError. Bem legal! Obrigado pela dica porém, me surgiu outra dúvida.

Ao executar o setError() o resultado é uma figura (oval com exclamação) de "aviso".
Devo configurar alguma coisa para aparecer o box? Algum layout ou parametro?

Comment: Como você está utilizando? como click? se voce puder colocar um print fica melhor para te orientar @CaioSanchezChristino

Comment: Estou usando click. Estou tentando implementar em uma listview e li um documento sobre a necessidade de utilizar notifyDataSetChanged.... Sabe se há a necessidade?

Já posto a foto

Comment: aparece apenas a image de exclamação, como nesta figura (http://i.stack.imgur.com/zXCJC.png)

Comment: Estou usando o aplicativo so SE, quando estiver num computador faço uma edição na minha resposta.

Comment: @CaioSanchezChristino, ainda está com problemas? acabei esquecendo de voc^!